# What is the difference between src and ng-src in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Recently I came across this:

```
 <img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{image}}">
```

What is the difference with:

```
 <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{image}}">
```

I get the data through a **http post** request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is at what point the image is loaded.

If you add `ng-src` it will first ***load/resolve*** the image data and will then apply it.

```
<img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{image}}">
```

Where as, if you directly use the:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{image}}">
```

Angular will first try to find the image, but since data is not loaded yet, it will throw the following error:

```
GET data:image/png;base64,{{image}} net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```